# How do I expire the cache for an ActionView::Template from my TemplateHandler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, caching

I have a custom template handler who's render method isn't being called predictably for my templates. Rails is caching the compiled template into a method and only re-rending the template if it's underlying file changes.

I'd like to to make this more sophisticated and add my own method of detecting stale templates.

The question is, how do manually expire a template's cache from my handler do that?

**EDIT:**

It looks like [this is where the magic is](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/template.rb#L142). When my template is rendered the first time `@compiled` is set to true. In certain situations, I need to change this to false so it recompiles my template. How can I do that from a template handler?

Comment: Are you using fragment caching, page caching, or action caching?

Comment: I'm not using any of those explicitly. So what ever the default is. I don't ever call the `cache` method in my templates if that helps. In fact I think the caching you're referring to is another part rails (though I'm not sure). I'm referring to the automatic caching they mention here (ctrl+f Template Caching): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Base.html

Comment: Ok.... so your modifying the erb/haml files at runtime in production then, or am I missing something?

Comment: I have template that uses an external resource during compilation. This resource is NOT another view/partial. When this external resource changes, the compiled template should be invalidated, but I don't know how to tell rails that the template it already compiled needs recompilation. How do I do that?

Comment: How are you calling the external resource, and what exactly is this external resource, another template? Second off it might help to have the external resource logic in a helper method depending on what the external resource is.

Comment: The resource is a javascript file containing global helpers. My template is compiled with a javascript runtime who's context contains these helpers. I need to invalidate the compiled template when these helpers change because they change the javascript compilation environment.